# How to distinguish these two insert functions

Tags: c++, stl, sfinae

My own list has two insert functions

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
auto list<T, Allocator>::insert(iterator pos, size_t count, const T & value)->iterator
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pos = insert(pos, value);
    }
    return pos;
}


template<typename T, typename Allocator>
template<typename ...Args>
 auto list<T, Allocator>::insert(iterator pos, Args && ...args) -> iterator
{
     auto ret_val = this->get_allocator().allocate(1);
     this->get_allocator().construct(ret_val, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
     auto new_node = new node<T>(ret_val);
     auto current_node = pos.l_node;
     new_node->n_next = current_node;
     new_node->n_prev = current_node->n_prev;
     current_node->n_prev->n_next = new_node;
     current_node->n_prev = new_node;
     return iterator(new_node);
}
```

Sometimes the compiler does not know which function should be called,For example, the following situation

```
list<int> l1;
l1.insert(l1.begin(),10, 2);
```

I expect the first function to be called, but in fact the second function is called,Then the following error will appear
`The compiler cannot cast from initializer_list to int.`

The code is here:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FxHPrdDHsj/

Comment: Personally I would use tag dispatch here and add a tag parameter to the variadic template so that it can be differentiated.  You can see an example of this if you look at `std::optional`. It has constructors that take a `std::in_place_t`.

Comment: `typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>>`I copied it from the optional constructor and it solved this problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is being called because it is a better match.

The first function wants three parameters `(iterator, size_t, int)`.

The second function wants N parameters `(iterator, stuff)`.

You're providing `(iterator, int, int)`.

Matching the first function requires an implicit conversion (`int` -> `size_t`). Matching the second one requires no conversions.

Change the call to `l1.insert(l1.begin(),(size_t) 10, 2)` and it should call the first one.

Comment: Still can't compile

Comment: I try to compile on gcc, but it will produce a compilation error on vs2017